# Playonlinux MS Office 2013 applications constantly in the foreground in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, ubuntu-gnome, playonlinux

I have successfully installed MS Office 2013. But e.g. an open Excel is constantly in the foreground unless I minimize the application manually.

And (second but maybe related problem) the minimized application is shown on the desktop and not visible in the task manager.

Can someone help?

Comment: New oberservation: If a file is opened through filemanager (nemo) via double click "default = PlayOnLinux" than the program is not running as normal ubuntu task, the behaviour is as described. 

But if the program (e.g. Excel) is started from the PlayOnLinux app directly it is integrated into the standard tasks as every other program task and Alt+Tab is doing like expected.

Comment: Oops. Observation is wrong. Accidentally I opened Excel-2010 (also with wine 3.0). There it is no problem. In Excel-2013 the problem is still as described.

Answer (score 0):

set `usetakefocus` to `n` or `disabled`

https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=35267&p=137242#p135820

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).